# How to speedup the requests query?

Tags: parallel-processing, python-requests, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to basically brute-force multiple links to check if the file exists in any of the links, is there any possibility that i can increase the speed of requests, maybe multiple request processes at the same time, because it's currently too slow.

```
import requests

for no in range(100000,500000):
    part1 = "https://url/"
    part2 = "_[12시.jpg"
    url = part1+str(no)+part2
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(url)
        break
    elif response.status_code == 404:
      print('Not Found @',no)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into the complexities of sending requests at the same time, here's an approach that will already speed up your calls by using [requests.Session](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

```
import requests


s = requests.Session()

for no in range(100000, 500000):
    url = f"https://url/{no}_[12시.jpg"
    response = s.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(url)
        break

    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print(f"Not Found @{no}")
```